# How do i subclass a UIView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, subclass

This may seem like a stupid question, but i can't quite remember how to subclass a UIView. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

example (.h file):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MySubclassedView : UIView 
{

}

@end
```

Or, just add a new class to your project and tell XCode to subclass `UIView` and the template will be created.